# Pro Micro COM port disappeared after upload

Tags: serial

I uploaded a sketch to my Pro Micro and it stopped showing in serial ports. Other Arduinos show up just fine.

I've tried to detect serial devices using pyserial and it's also not seeing anything. I've tried to reset the board by connecting the reset pin to ground twice in quick succession but it's not doing anything.

The board might be broken, but it seems unlikely to me as it's not connected to anything high powered.

The sketch I uploaded does use serial, but that hasn't been a problem before.

Any ideas on how to recover the board?

Comment: If it's a variety of pro micro that takes a micro-b cable, make sure you've not been trying to connect it with a power-only type of USB cable.

Comment: @timemage It's a mini usb and I've checked a few cables. Couldn't really be the issue as it worked before. I'm afraid it just decided to die on me :/

Comment: I wasn't there to observe that the same cable being used twice. *"not connected to anything high powered"* I would update with details on what happens if it's connected to nothing at all, except USB. If that is impractical I would update a volt meter reading of the 5V/VCC pin. Whether or not your *"Other Arduinos"* are also of Pro Micro type may be helpful. When you say *"does use serial"* are you referring to `Serial1` (USART) or `Serial` (as in over USB). If you're leaving it all connected, clear images and wiring diagrams/schematics.

Comment: Since Pro-Micro comes as 3.3V and 5V, see past Q of [mine](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79313/upload-s-sketch-to-a-5v-pro-micro-board-as-3-3v-by-mistake)

Answer (score 0):

The Pro Micro uses a single processor (ATmega32U4) unlike some of the other Arduinos which have a separate processor for USB communications.

When reset, it will appear as a USB device for a couple of seconds, and then if the sketch does not use Serial, or uses it inappropriately, it could stop responding. For example, if the code went into a loop.

It is highly unlikely that the board just "broke". I suggest keeping the processor in Reset (tie Reset to Ground) while you compile a new sketch, and then release Reset when it tells you it is starting to upload.

You haven't posted your code, but it quite possibly is the problem. For example, you might have disabled interrupts.